# Search singapore address using postal code in android app

Tags: android, google-maps

i want to search singapore address using **postal code** in **android app**, like if i put postal code in edittext field **436914** then press a button and it will return address 
**"121 Tanjong Rhu Road, Singapore 436914"**

i am using android geocode class but it gives address not exactly as i want, it gives me
 **Singapore 436914** only
and the below link as well
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=436914&sensor=true

Comment: I just tested your example on Google Maps and he also show "Singapore 436914", so I think is a problem with Google Maps and not your code, https://maps.google.com.br/maps?q=436914

Comment: Does every address in Singapore have a unique postcode? This would be unusual, generally a building identifier is required as well. If you're trying to get a list of valid addresses, you'll need to find an address searching library (which will most likely not be free) for Singapore.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying but there is an app in google play store called "singapore postal code" this app returning building name as well and full address.  Like if i search 436914, this will return building name : tanjong ria condominium, block : 121, road name : tanjong rhu road.

Comment: Now I found two alternative to get address using postal code, http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=436914&sensor=true link gives the latitude and longitude recall the same url but now instead of address parameter pass latlong parameter, and its value in two process you will get exact address.

Comment: Second alternative in android, pass postal code to the function and get latitude and longitude, and then call the different function and pass latitude and longitude in the second functin you will get exect address, List<Address> addresses1 = geocoder.getFromLocationName (val_pcode, 1);
        
         Address obj1 = addresses1.get(0);
         
         List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(obj1.getLatitude(), obj1.getLongitude(), 1);
         Address obj = addresses.get(0);

Answer (score 1):

Now I found two alternative to get address using postal code, http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=436914&sensor=true link gives the latitude and longitude recall the same url but now instead of address parameter pass latlong parameter, and its value in two process you will get exact address.

second alternative is

```
public void getAddressByPostalCode(String val_pcode) {

    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());

    try {           

        List<Address> addresses1 = geocoder.getFromLocationName (val_pcode, 1);

        Address obj1 = addresses1.get(0);

        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(obj1.getLatitude(), obj1.getLongitude(), 1);
        Address obj = addresses.get(0);
        EditText street = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        EditText pcode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        EditText blk = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText13);
        EditText build = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.buildingtext);

        street.setText(obj.getThoroughfare());
        pcode.setText(obj.getPostalCode());
        blk.setText(obj.getSubThoroughfare());
        build.setText(obj.getPremises());


    } catch (IOException e) {
       Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

}

Comment: This solution does not work reliably. Example: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=417396&components=country:SG&sensor=true -- the returned location is way off.

Answer (score 0):

For Postal Code, I find that the data from onemap.sg is pretty accurate. However for some postal code, there will be more than one result. This is because there might be multiple listing of the same postal code within the same building. Nevertheless, it is still accurate.

For simplicity, I would recommend looking at this [github repo](https://github.com/xkjyeah/singapore-postal-codes) on the usage of the api.

The key fields to look at will be Address, Building, SearchVal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it.
[Geocode.xyz/SG](https://geocode.xyz/436914?region=SG)

```
{
"standard": {
"addresst": "121 TANJONG RHU ROAD",
"stnumber": "121",
"prov": "SG",
"city": "Singapore",
"countryname": "Singapore",
"postal": "436914",
"confidence": "0.5"
},
"longt": "103.87430",
"alt": {
"loc": {
  "longt": "103.87430",
  "city": "Singapore",
  "cc": "2",
  "latt": "1.29662"
}
},
"latt": "1.29662"
}
```